# Best way to fetch PHP array in an external file not properly formatted?

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

I'm fetching a file in my file system that has many arrays like this:

```
$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['status_list_Life']=array (
  '' => '',
  'Entered' => 'Entered',
  'VA' => 'Active',
  'SU' => 'Surrendered',
  'MA' => 'Matured',
  'DE' => 'Deceased/Death Claim',
  'AN' => 'Annuitized',
  'PB' => 'Letter of Authorization Sent',
  'PD' => 'Pended',
  'CC' => 'Cancelled',
  'FL' => 'Free Look',
  'NT' => 'Not Taken',
  'DA' => 'Deferred Death',
  'LP' => 'Lapsed',
  'SI' => 'Surrender to the client',
  'SE' => 'Surrender/Exchanged to a third party',
  'SC' => 'Surrender/Converted',
  'OD' => 'One Deceased',
  'AA' => 'Active Annuity Payout',
  'TT' => 'Termination',
  'PU' => 'Paid Up',
  'RD' => 'Rescinded',
  'LD' => 'Lapse Pending',
);
```

I've done a file_get_contents() to get the file, and used PHP's strstr() to narrow it down to just this array.

I'm having problems parsing through it via a for/foreach loop due to the invalid formatting.

What would be the best way for me to be able to loop through and access these values while fetching the file/array?

My attempt that doesn't work...

```
$file = file_get_contents('myfilename');

$array = strstr($file, "$" . "GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['status_list_Life']");

$new = str_replace('\n', '', $array);

print_r($new);
```

Comment: It seems if the external script are valid PHP, you should simply be using include/require on them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I see to do it. I am getting the contents of the file and then getting the string after the equals sign and reformating the string so it sets the variable array equal to the rest of the code. Then I used eval to execute the code.

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$needle = "GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['status_list_Life']";
$rest = substr(strstr($file, $needle), strlen($needle));
$rest = "$"."array".$rest;
eval($rest);
print_r($array);
?>
```